# Android - Touch event stops working

Tags: android

This is my touch event:

```
.myImageViewsetOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//OUTPUT TRACE
```

The problem is, after moving around a bit, it stops outputing under action move.

What am I doing wrong?

```
myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int myX = (int)event.getX();
            int myY = (int)event.getY();
            int color = pngTestBM.getPixel(myX,myY); // x and y are the location of the touch event in Bitmap space
            int alpha = Color.alpha(color);

            switch (event.getAction()) {


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                if(alpha==0){
                    System.out.println("blank");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("no");

                }


            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:



                if(alpha==0){
                    System.out.println("blank");

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("no");
                }



            break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: post the whole class' source code

Comment: does it switch to a different action? or just stop giving you callbacks all together?

Comment: Ive posted more code, the alpha check prints 'blank' then when you move over the image it prints 'no' then stops working altogether after a few prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try debugging using this method. Call it at the beginning. Also add a default case. btw.. use Log.d instead of System.out

```
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,
             "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          int action = event.getAction();
          int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
          sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);
          if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
             sb.append("(pid " ).append(
             action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
             sb.append(")" );
          }
          sb.append("[" );
          for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
             sb.append("#" ).append(i);
             sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));
             sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));
             sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));
             if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";" );
          }
          sb.append("]" );
          Log.d("event", sb.toString());
       }
```

Comment: This outputs loads of action moves and then for some reason it does an action cancel. I still have my finder down though.

Comment: ACTION_CANCEL means a parent is taking control of the onTouch events. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL  .  Does your app have scroll functionality or anything else that would deal w/ anytype of touchevent